# why is this the partial solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $y''(x)-y'(x)= \sin (x)$, I have to find it's solution.

I found the homogeneous solution and I thought that the partial solution would be $(Ax+B) \sin x+(Cx+D) \cos x$, because of the fact that $r_{1}=0$ is a solution of the characteristic equation.

But I found that the partial solution is $A \sin x+ B \cos x$. Why is it like that?

Comment: By partial solution do you mean particular solution, related to $\sin (x)$?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put $$(Ax+B)\sin x+(Cx+d)\cos x$$ when $\sin$ and $\cos$ are the homogeneous solutions.

You probably misinterpreted this as $r=0$ is solution to the caracteristic equation, because this is what happens when the RHS is a polynomial.

In general, if RHS is $P(x)e^{kx}$ for some $k$ and polynomial $P$, you have to find your particular solution of the form $Q(x)e^{kx}$ with $\deg Q=\deg P$ if $k$ is not a root, and $\deg Q=\deg P + 1$ if $k$ is a root of the caracteristic equation. Here, you have $\sin(x)=\frac 1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ and neither $i$ or $-i$ is a root of the caracteristic equation, so you can take $A\sin x+B\cos x$.